# Execute javascript in an ascx.cs usercontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wpf, obout

I'm dynamically adding controls to my ascx.cs usercontrol and therefore I also need to dynamically execute javascript code from my ascx.cs usercontrol.

I'm executing my javascript using:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "reOpen", "<script type='text/javascript'> reOpenClick(); </script>")
```

This is my javascript in the ascx file

```
<%@ Register Assembly="obout_Window_NET" Namespace="OboutInc.Window" TagPrefix="obout" %>

<obout:Window runat="server" ID="ow_dialog" Width="200" Height="50"
    Title="Open" IsModal="true" ShowCloseButton="true"
    StyleFolder="~/Styles/obout/window/grandgray" VisibleOnLoad="false">    
   .
   .
   .
   .
</obout:Window>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function reOpenClick() {
        ow_dialog.setTitle("Open");
        ow_dialog.screenCenter();
        ow_dialog.Open();
    }

</script>
```

When running the code as usual I'm getting the error `ReferenceError: ow_dialog is not defined`. But when typing reOpenClick() into the web browser's console everything runs fine.

Why am I getting the `ReferenceError: ow_dialog is not defined` when typing in the function in the console works fine?

Answer (score 2):

Add script tags to the markup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // place your javascript here
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" href="path to js file" />
```

or

In the `load` event of your control, do something like this:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("keyName"))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("keyName",
        Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jsfile.js"));
```

If the user control is in an `UpdatePanel` and/or its `Visible` attribute is set to false by default, you will get `"Object expected"` error because simply your script is *not* loaded when the page loads and the function you are calling is non-existent.

Workaround for this is to use `style="display:none"` instead of `Visible="false"` for your user control in the *main* page.